# Multi-jail /var separation

Tags: freebsd, webserver, jails

I'm setting up multiple jails in FreeBSD to serve dynamic websites. The host environment has a webserver that dispatches connection based on HTTP Host header, and each jail has a /var/lib/www-db directory containing per-site data.

The problem is, I'm creating multiple jails, by mount_nullfs'ing a template jail onto actual jails' directories, and although I've separately mounted /var/lib/www-db, the jails still shares /var/log and other directories in the /var hierarchy.

I realize this is somewhat a security concern to have /var/log and some other directories shared, so my question is

- What's the best practice in with setting up multiple jails?

**Update**

I've used ZFS: I've a zpool of two large disks which contains subdirectories to be mounted as /var/lib/www-db in jails.

Comment: You might help answerers by adding to the question whether you are already using ZFS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution that allows jail to modify its root (which includes /var and /tmp which are both important) while keeping the "template" intact in FreeBSD.

Procedures:

1. Create root directory for the jail, here denoted as `<jail-root>`
2. Mount the template directory using unionfs "below" `<jail-root>` using the command:

   `mount_unionfs -o below <template> <jail-root>`

In this way, each jail has an entire root hierarchy available, and can be written to incrementally without consuming too much storage.

**References**

[FreeBSD Man Page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount_unionfs&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports)

> Requests to create or modify objects in uniondir are passed to the upper layer with the exception of a few special cases. An attempt to open for writing a file which exists in the lower layer causes a copy of the entire file to be made to the upper layer, and then for the upper layer copy to be opened. Similarly, an attempt to truncate a lower layer file to zero length causes an empty file to be created in the upper layer. Any other operation which would ultimately require modification to the lower layer fails with EROFS.